# Set interval gets clear on browser refresh in my react application

Tags: reactjs, authentication, setinterval, browser-refresh

I am using the `setInterval` function to do an API call to get refresh token after some interval. Every time if I refresh the browser `setInterval` timer gets clear and starts counting from zero. My access token gets expired and the refresh token never getting a call and user logged out. Is there any way to deal with this?

```
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => { 
    setTokenByReSendingAuth(); //dispatch action
  }, 300000);

  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [setTokenByReSendingAuth]);
```

Comment: Create an expiration date/time string in the user object of your collection. When the initial date and time is created it is set in the database user object. Next time the user refreshes the page, have it auto request that initial date and replace it with the current date. If the date is greater than the previous, then it is expired. In other words, dont use set interval.

Comment: then how I deal with continuous call after some interval?

Comment: attach your token to the header of each request.

Comment: are you using express?

Comment: I agree with @user67. It's typical to check expiration on each network request. Thats where most of your security is concerned. A client could easily disable that timer on the front-end. So instead of a "timer" you have the server keep track of expiration time, or track it in something (token) that only the server can make.

Comment: Is this the only feasible way?! There is 100 + plus apis and to modify each one to get current time is seems hard way.. I just want to user logged in when they actively using our application.   Note:- token expire time is only 30 minutes..  I have to get refresh token before 30 min. If user is working

Comment: I am already passing access token to each request currently and  with authentication api I am getting expire time at frontend

Comment: what stack are you using, i might be able to show you an example?

Comment: React in frontend and Laravel as backend @user67

Comment: @MeetChothani oh, sorry im only familiar with mern.

Comment: let me know if you found any way to implement it with the MERN stack. @user67

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using MERN:

Heres your dependencies:

**jwt-decode:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode

**passport-jwt:** http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-jwt/

**passport:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport

**jsonwebtoken:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken

**bcryptjs:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs

Create an express server.js like this:

```js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const path = require("path");
const passport = require("passport");
const db = require("./config/.env").mongoURI; //uri in .env file

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

mongoose.connect(db, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once("open", () => {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
});

const myRouter = require("./routes/example.js");

app.use(passport.initialize()); // used to attatch token to request headers
require("./config/passport")(passport); 

app.use("/example", myRouter);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

Install your dependencies:

```js
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.8",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "validator": "^13.5.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  },
```

Add this to your package.json in whatever directory your server is in:

```js
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js"
  },
```

Now to the Auth part:

Make a config folder for your passport and URI:

In a .env file:

```js
module.exports = {
  mongoURI: "mongodb+srv://",
  secretOrKey: "abunchofrandomcharacterscreatedwithbcrypt",
};
```

Make a passport.js file:

This adds the user's token to all request headers, it is automatically running since we used it in our server.js file.

```js
const JwtStrategy = require("passport-jwt").Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require("passport-jwt").ExtractJwt;
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = mongoose.model("users");
const keys = require("./.env");

const opts = {};
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
opts.secretOrKey = keys.secretOrKey;

module.exports = (passport) => {
  passport.use(
    new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
      User.findById(jwt_payload.id)
        .then((user) => {
          if (user) {
            return done(null, user);
          }
          return done(null, false);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    })
  );
};
```

Make a middleware folder for your backend:

Add an auth.js file:

```js
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const config = require("../config/.env").secretOrKey;

function authUser(req, res, next) {
  const authHeader = req.header("Authorization");
  const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(" ")[1];
  // Check for token
  if (!token)
    return res.status(401).json({ msg: "No token, authorization denied" });

  try {
    // Verify token
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config);
    // Add user from payload
    req.user = decoded;
    next();
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).json({ msg: "Token is not valid" });
  }
}

module.exports = {
  authUser,
};
```

This file is attached to your routes in the header, like this:

```js
router.post("/example/get", authUser, (req, res) => { 
  const { reqData } = req.body; //dont ever put user ids in here
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(400).json({ msg: err });
    });
});
```

The route to login and register should look like this:

```js
const router = require("express").Router();
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const { authUser } = require("../middleware/auth"); //used in the header of auth needed requests
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const keys = require("../config/.env");
const validateRegisterInput = require("../validation/register"); //checks and validates  user register inputs
const validateLoginInput = require("../validation/login"); //checks and validates user register inputs
const User = require("../models/user");
const { Permissions } = require("../models/permissions");

//uses a middleware to validate register inputs, checks if user data exists in db, salts and hashes the password.

router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  const { errors, isValid } = validateRegisterInput(req.body);

  if (!isValid) {
    return res.status(400).json(errors);
  }

  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then((user) => {
    if (user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ email: "Email already exists" });
    } else {
      const newUser = new User({
        firstName: req.body.firstName,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
      });

      bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          newUser.password = hash;
          newUser
            .save()
            .then((user) => res.json(user))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        });
      });
    }
  });
});

//login creds are req through this route, the details are compared to the db user collection, and the user data that matches the decoded password and username will be responed back through the token.

router.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const { errors, isValid } = validateLoginInput(req.body);
  if (!isValid) {
    return res.status(400).json(errors);
  }

  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;

  User.findOne({ email }).then((user) => {
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ email: "Email not found" });
    }

    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then((isMatch) => {
      if (isMatch) {
        const payload = {
          id: user.id,
          firstName: user.firstName,
        };

        jwt.sign(
          payload,
          keys.secretOrKey,
          {
            expiresIn: 31556926, //expires in a year
          },
          (err, token) => {
            res.json({
              success: true,
              token: "Bearer " + token,
            });
          }
        );
      } else {
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json({ passwordincorrect: "Password incorrect" });
      }
    });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

That's basically it for the backend auth routing side of things, but for the client to get there token in the browser you need to add this stuff to the client:

In your index.js add this outside a component to run on every render no matter what:

This checks to see if there's a jwttoken in the browser, it decodes it and sets the user data into the state to be used globally. It also redirects the user.

```js
import setAuthToken from "./utils/setAuthToken";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

if (localStorage.jwtToken) {
  // Set auth token header auth
  const token = localStorage.jwtToken;
  setAuthToken(token);
  // Decode token and get user info and exp
  const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
  // Set user and isAuthenticated
  store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded)); // using redux, can easily also just use contextApi or something else
  // Check for expired token
  const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000; // to get in milliseconds
  if (decoded.exp < currentTime) {
    // Logout user
    store.dispatch(logoutUser());

    // Redirect to login
    window.location.href = "./";
  }
}
```

Create login, register and logout functions:

```js
import axios from "axios";
import setAuthToken from "../../utils/setAuthToken";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

import { SET_CURRENT_USER } from "./authTypes"; //puts user data into state
import { showSnackbar } from "../inventory/inventoryActions";

export const registerUser = (userData) => (dispatch) => {
  axios
    .post("/users/register", userData)
    .then(() => {
    console.log("logged in")
    })
    .catch(() => {
     console.log("something wrong")
    });
};

export const loginUser = (userData) => (dispatch) => {
  axios
    .post("/users/login", userData)
    .then((res) => {
      const { token } = res.data;
      localStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token);
      setAuthToken(token);
      const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
      dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
      dispatch(showSnackbar(`Successfully signed in!`, "success", 3000));
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log("somethings wrong")
    });
};

export const setCurrentUser = (decoded) => { // used in loginUser
  return {
    type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
    payload: decoded,
  };
};

//removes token from localstorage
export const logoutUser = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    localStorage.removeItem("jwtToken");
    setAuthToken(false);
    dispatch(setCurrentUser({}));
  };
};
```

If you have any private components you only want logged in users to access use this PrivateRoute Component wrapper:

This redirects any user not logged in to the home page

```js
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) =>
      auth.isAuthenticated === true ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/" />
      )
    }
  />
);

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  auth: state.auth,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

Use it as a react-router-dom element:

```
<PrivateRoute exact path="/example" component={privateComponentExample} />
```

If you have any questions, let me know. :)